# Gitlab CI - Split deployment script from build script

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

## Problem description

I have a **.gitlab-ci.yaml** like this:

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

before_script:
  - docker login ...

build:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - dind
  script:
    - docker pull $CONTAINER_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME || true
    - docker build ...
    - docker push $CONTAINER_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
    - docker push $CONTAINER_IMAGE:git-$CI_COMMIT_SHA

manual-deploy-dev:
  image: 'google/cloud-sdk:latest'
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - dind
  when: manual
  script:
    - echo "$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_DEV_KEY" > key.json
    - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=key.json
    - docker login -u _json_key --password-stdin https://gcr.io < key.json
    - docker pull xxx:git-$CI_COMMIT_SHA
    - docker tag xxx:git-$CI_COMMIT_SHA xxx:git-$CI_COMMIT_SHA
    - docker push xxx
```

My problem is that since .gitlab-ci.yaml lives in the same branch as the software it implies that if I need to update the deployment script I have to recompile the software for that. And also the hash of the build changes needlessly.

## What I want

I'd like to have my code in the **master branch** and changes should retrigger a build. I would like to have the deployment scripts versioned in the deployment-scripts branch on the same repository.

- branch master - code for the application
- branch deployment-scripts - code for the deployment

And if the deployment-script fails I want to be able to fix it without having to touch the other code.

## What I tried

### Use before_script

```
before_script:
      - docker login ...
      - git checkout deployment-scripts
```

The problem with this solution is that in the .gitlab-ci.yaml there can be only one before_script for all stages and for the build stage I want the 'master' branch and for the 'manual-deploy-dev' I want the deployment-scripts.

**This can't work.**

### Using multi_project_pipelines (with one GL project)

Michael Delgado proposed to use https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/multi_project_pipelines.html

But there is a limitation in GL discussed in https://forum.gitlab.com/t/downstream-pipeline-trigger-definition-is-invalid/52356/5 which implies that you need to use two different projects for it to work. In my setup I want to have two different branches.

**This can't work with just one GL project.**

### Using multi_project_pipelines (with two GL projects)

Going with this proposal could easily mean that I would have to have around 6 or 8 more projects for all our different deployment targets in different projects.

**This probably works but I'd rather try to avoid that.**

### Using get raw files from repository with PRIVATE-TOKEN

First I created a read only 'developer' token and for testing hardcoded it into the request. Later I put that token into the environment variables.

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: xxx" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/567/repository/files/upload_google.sh/raw?ref=deployment-scripts" -o upload_google.sh
```

Turns out, this is actually the easiest way to do it ATM.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html#get-raw-file-from-repository

## Solution

**I use a PRIVATE-TOKEN with the get-raw-file-from-repository method.**

Comment: Why not have two repos and trigger builds on the deployment repo when the code repo changes? Using branches to hold totally divergent code bases is really not how git is intended to be used.  Instead, this seems like a great case for [multi-project pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/multi_project_pipelines.html)

Comment: I gave this a shot but found this: https://forum.gitlab.com/t/downstream-pipeline-trigger-definition-is-invalid/52356/5 and it seems that I can't trigger the same project with a different branch (a limitation of gitlab I suppose). I will try with the proposed before_script again and do a 'git checkout deployment_scripts'

Comment: Yeah I’m suggesting you put your build and deploy in different projects not different branches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a PRIVATE-TOKEN with the get-raw-file-from-repository method as outlined in the Solution section of the question.

```
- 'curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $READ_ONLY_CI_GOOGLE_UPLOAD_SCRIPT" "https://gitlab.xxx.com/api/v4/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/repository/files/upload_google.sh/raw?ref=deployment-scripts" -o upload_google.sh'
```

Also notice the $CI_PROJECT_ID usage.